# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: Request failed with status code 400). If you meant to render a collection of children,

Tags: reactjs, redux

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: Request failed with status code 400). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I am not able to understand whats doing wrong here

```
const { error, loading }: CreateUserState = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.createUser);

  return (
        <>
            <GDialog title="User Management" open={open} showDialog={showDialog}>
                {loading === false && error !== "" ? <Alert>{error}</Alert> : <></>}
                <form id="request-new-form" className="groundup-form" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                    <GFormInput<UserFormFields> formik={formik} id="username" label="User Name" />
                    <GFormInput<UserFormFields> formik={formik} id="email" label="Email" />
                </form >
            </GDialog >
        </>
    )
```

[image: Error I am getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `error` is an object, not a string. Try to use this

`{loading === false && error !== "" ? <Alert>{JSON.stringify(error)}</Alert> : <></>}`

If you see and object in the alert then you need to create the case when `error` is not a string.